# Export/Outputs that don't exist preventing stack from updating/deleting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, serverless

Using serverless to deploy to AWS.

I created a Cognito user pool via serverless then realised I wanted to change it's attributes.

I couldn't deploy because you can't update attributes on an existing user pool.

"No problem - I'll just delete it and make it again" I thought.  So I did.

But I had created two Outputs that referencing Client ID and Pool ID so now I get this:

`Export alpha-UserPoolId cannot be deleted as it is in use by alpha-Stack`

I can't see any way to remove theese references manually via the AWS console.

Anyone know what I can do to remove these dead references?

There's no option to manually remove an Output and I tried editing the template but it didn't seem to actually do anything.

Thanks

[EDIT: Check comments for full details on solution]

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the importing stack to not rely on these values, afterwards you can remove them.

As long as there is an `Fn::ImportValue` somewhere, it won't let you delete the export.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html):

> The following restrictions apply to cross stack references
> ...
>
> - You can't delete a stack if another stack references one of its outputs.
> - You can't modify or remove an output value that is referenced by another stack.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quick :)

Comment: The stack is the same stack and the references are removed already.  It's like it doesn't realise it's the same stack.

Comment: Why would you use that in the same stack - Ref and GetAtt are built for that? I suggest you take the current template from the console, remove the imports, update the stack with it and then you should be able to delete the stack.

Comment: My intention was just to have the created user pool id and client id available in Lambda. ie: ```    environment:
      USER_POOL_ID: !ImportValue ${self:provider.stage}-UserPoolId
      USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID: !ImportValue ${self:provider.stage}-UserPoolClientId```

I will try the template editing again.

Comment: Editing the template to remove all references gives me the same error.

Comment: In the first step you need to **only** get rid of the imports! This is a two step process!

Comment: You're totally right!  The references were still there in the template so I removed those first, updated with new template then did the same process with the outputs!